# How do you use inverseTimes()?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you use inverseTimes?

From reading the docs, it looks like it should be a member function of Transform(), and take another Transform() as the argument.

However, the following code:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Transform
my_tf1 = Transform()
my_tf2 = Transform()
my_tf1.translation.x = 2
my_tf2.translation.x = 5
my_tf1.inverseTimes(my_tf2)
```

produces the error:

> AttributeError: 'Transform' object has no attribute 'inverseTimes'

Is there a different object in tf called Transform that I should be using instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211344/how-do-you-use-inversetimes()?/) by [CatherineH](https://answers.ros.org/users/22373/catherineh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2015-06-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2015-06-15**:
I've noticed that some tf functions from c++ are not available in python... I can't think of a workaround that is quicker than implementing this function yourself :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`inverseTimes` is a member of `tf::Transform` in the C++ API. I don't see any equivalent in Python. I'm sure you can do the same thing with numpy (or possibly PyKDL) though.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0